# Add a member to a group from another domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to create a script to add a user of my main domain to a group of my secondary domain.

I have two user (`userA` and `userB`) on my main domain `domainA` and I need to add those users to 150 groups on my secondary domain `domainB`.

I've got a script to do exactly what I want, but only works on the current domain were I run the script. it cannot execute for another (remote) domain.

```
import-csv path_csv_file.csv | % {Add-ADGroupMember $_.groupname –Members $_.users }
```

The CSV contains the groups from DomainB are in Column A (`groupname`) and the users from DomainA that I have in column B (`users`).

Comment: Do you domains have trust between them?

Comment: I think this is not a programming / PowerShell related question. It's more a general question on adding users to anothers domains, isn't it? You didn't told us much about your domains it's trusting, relation etc.

Comment: By default `Add-ADGroupMember` will look at the domain the computer it's running on is joined to. You need to use the `Server` param to specify a domain controller on DomainB eg `Add-ADGroupMember $_.groupname –Members $_.users -Server domaincontroller01.domainb.com`. (This assuming trusts are setup correctly between domains, which is a question for serverfault.com not stackoverflow)

Comment: The domains are trusted.

@JamesC. I'll try the tip and gave you the feedback

Comment: @JamesC. You are forgetting that the domains likely have two diff credentials. He needs to give each domain the proper credentials

Comment: @JamesC. I already tried with the -Server parameter and doesn't work.
It's seams the connection only pointing to the server that I determine on the parameter.

It I put this -> import-csv path_csv_file.csv | % {Add-ADGroupMember $_.groupname –Members $_.users -Server hostnameB.tla.domainB.local}
The command will assume that I want the connection only for hostnameB.tla.domainB.local so we can't recognize the user name that I have on the domainA, reporting these error: Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'user' under: 'DC=tla,DC=domainB,DC=local'.

Comment: As you're are working across domains, your usernames should be properly qualified like `domainA\username`

Comment: I've tried that too, but no success.
I'm login on my machine (is associated to domainA) and I have domain admin permissions. I run the script directly on my machine but when I put import-csv path_csv_file.csv | % {Add-ADGroupMember –Members $_.users $_.groupname -Server serverDC.tla.domainB.local -Credential domainA\domain_admin} I retrive the same error: Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'domain_admin' under: 'DC=tla,DC=domainB,DC=local'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I've already solve the problem.

So I find out the script that allow me to add a user from domainA to a group on domainB.

This is the solution:

```
$Group = import-csv path_csv_file.csv | % {Get-ADGroup $_.groupname -Server serverB.tla.domainB.local}
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership user_domainA -MemberOf $Group
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer I can give you with what you gave me.

You are missing two essential parameters to `Add-ADGroupMember`

You can specify a different domain with:

`-Server domain.example.com`

You will most likely have to specify different credentials for a different domain as well:

`-Credential (Get-Credentials)`

Since you are doing this in two different domains, store two different credentials:

```
$domain1_credentials = Get-Credentials # Give domain1\username - password
$domain2_credentials = Get-Credentials # Give domain2\username - password
```

Comment: I think the problem isn't on the credentials, because I'm a domain admin on the two domains. The problem it's about the connection to the differents domains, like i anwser (now) in above.